# how to use cocos2d-x 3.x expansion apk

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0, apk-expansion-files

i have been looking for google play store expansion for several days but i got no idea how to use it.

my app goes over 60Mb.

can somebody help me how to do it from the start?

---

i had a solution by changing my fileutils-android and helperjava.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are running over 10 mb.
The best solution is to reduce your apk size as:-

1. Convert all pngs into jpegs.
2. Check and remove unused resources.

In case this does not work:-
Use this link:-
[how to make obb file](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html)